# Does absolutely flat commutative ring imply all ideals are idempotent?

Tags: reference-request, commutative-algebra, modules, ideals

From reading Atiyah and MacDonald, I know of the result that a absolutely flat commutative ring has all principal ideals idempotent.

Reading around on [math reference](http://www.mathreference.com/mod-hom-te,absflat.html), I think that if a commutative ring $R$ is absolutely flat (that is, all $R$-modules are flat), then every ideal $H$ is idempotent, so $H^2=H$.

However, maybe my English is not so good, but I don't fully understand the proof provided there. I don't get the language "descend into tensor algebra and imagine..." and such. Is there a better polished proof of why all ideals in a absolutely flat ring $R$ are idempotent? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think they are saying this. Given an ideal $I$, tensor the inclusion
$$
0 \to I \to R 
$$
with $R/I$. We get (flatness of $R/I$)
$$
0 \to I/I^2 \to R/I.
$$
Thus $I/I^2 = 0$, so $I = I^2$.

Comment: (I am using the fact that whenever $I$ is an ideal in a ring $R$ and $M$ is an $R$-module, we have $M \otimes R/I = M/IM$.)

Comment: Why does from the exactness of $
0 \to I/I^2 \to R/I
$ follow that $I/I^2 = 0$?

Comment: @mathcourse because the image of $I\otimes_R R/I\simeq I/I^2$ is zero in $R\otimes_R R/I$, the sequence being exact means that $I\otimes_R R/I=0$.

Answer (score 2):

This holds for noncommutative rings as well. If you are aware that "absolutely flat" is sometimes called "von Neumann regular", then you know that every finitely generated ideal of $R$ is generated by an idempotent.

If $I$ were an ideal with $I^2\subsetneq I$, pick $x\in I\setminus I^2$. Then $(xR)^2=(eR)^2=eR=xR$. But this means that $x\in (xR)^2\subseteq I^2$, a contradiction. So, $I^2=I$.